# change font within a shape ppt

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm automatically generating a powerpoint slide through VBA, User Forms, and Excel. You run the VBA script in excel, fill out the data, the data goes into cells in excel, then the VBA script pulls the data and puts it into textbox shapes in the slide.

My problem is I want to use different font sizes at different times, so for example 28 pt font for one part and 14 pt for the rest. The problem is that any property changes I make to the textbox applies to all of the text within the shape.

My current workaround is sloppy and is to just generate another textbox over the original and insert spacing in the original so it looks like the larger text is "in" the textbox while it's actually just sitting over a few empty lines set aside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format specific substrings within a string, but it's very cumbersome, for example assuming `shp` is an object variable representing your textbox:

```
Sub foo()
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox 3")
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hello, world!"
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = 14 'applies uniform font to entire shape
    shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(1, 5).Characters.Font.Size = 28

End Sub
```

Example output:

[image]

The difficulty of course is working with mixed formats, and I do not think there is any **easy** solution. It will be up to you to determine what formats you need to "capture", and what subsequently implement the appropriate conditional logic to transfer those formats to the PowerPoint shapes.

One possible alternative -- and this is the route that I would go if I were you -- would be to copy the *cell* from Excel, and use this method to paste in to PowerPoint.  I believe this will create a *table* consisting of a single cell, in the PowerPoint slide.  You will have to make adjustments for size/position, but this should be an order of magnitude easier than trying to capture every possible variation of font formatting:

```
Sub foo2()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim xl As Object

    'Get Excel and copy a specific cell
    Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks("Book35").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B4").Copy

    'Paste that cell in to PowerPoint as a table, preserving formats:
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Select
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"

End Sub
```

Example output, as copied from the Excel cell:

[image]

Comment: Seeing as how the first word will always appear at the start of the textbox's string, this is definitely a workable solution! Thank you so much! Now I can delete those nasty fake shapes :)

Answer (score -1):

No need to change the font in excel to reflect in Word. You can do it directly. Just paste the below mentinoed line in Word VBA : -
Activedocument.Shapes("sam").TextFrame.TextRange.Words(1).Font.Size = 28

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer my question, but maybe you misunderstood based on David's answer? I'm not working with word, I'm working with Powerpoint, specifically a textbox. Editing the font property on a textbox applies to all of the text, so his character-explicit workaround does just fine. Thank you for trying to help though!